# Как отловить потерю фокуса с компонента?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular5

Есть компонент улучшенный dropbox и при потере фокуса я хочу скрыть выпадающий список. Вот код

```
import { Attribute, Component, Input, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropbox-comp',
  templateUrl: './dropbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropbox.component.scss']
})
export class DropboxComponent{
  @Input() selected: object;
  @Input() array: [];

  @Output() selectedChange = new EventEmitter<object>();

  public isOpen = false;

  constructor(@Attribute('tabindex') public tabIndex: number = 0) {}

  toggle(){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  change_value(item){
    this.selectedChange.emit(item);
  }

  @HostListener("blur") //Не работает
  lostfocus(){
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

}
```

Разметка

```
<div class="dropdown selectDropdown" [ngClass]="{'open': isOpen}" (click)="toggle()" (blur)="lostfocus()">
  <ul (blur)="lostfocus()">
    <li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index" (click)="change_value(item)"><a>{{item.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span>{{selected['name']}}</span>
</div>
```

подключение

```
    <app-dropbox-comp [array]="store['sortCarsParameters']['data']"  
 [selected]="store['sortCarsParameters']['selected']"></app-dropbox-comp>
```

Comment: слушай событие `document click` и проверяй что пользователь кликнул вне дропдауна, и закрывай его :)

Comment: Как-то вроде как с пушки по воробьям. Это постоянно делать проверки, а если компонентов 1000? Я хочу что-то найти про потерю фокуса, но div ul не поддерживают это

Comment: стандартное решение для такого рода задач :) если ты б гуглил перед тем как задавал вопрос, то видел бы, что есть даже статьи с созданием дропдауна =)

Comment: @overthesanity это вы где такие статьи читаете? больше никому не показывайте)

Comment: @Yugofx я бы не начинал так беседу, _Use Google, Luce! (c)_ =)

Comment: @Yugofx https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/util/autoclose.ts#L34 . Передам Диме, чтоб они это никому не показывали, с отсылкой на твой комментарий 

Comment: @overthesanity а для вас всегда писатели библиотек непоколебимые гуру?

Comment: человек, который изначально это писал - Паша, так же в кор команде Angular и один из разработчиков Ivy компилятора, поэтому да - он для меня гуру. Уж извини, если так... 

Comment: Я тоже на ты предпочитаю) Тебе не за что извинятся. Твои гуру - это твои гуру. Не теряй голову от их решений. Все стоит подвергать анализу

Comment: @Yugofx дружище, если ты хочешь подискутировать со мной, то я не вступаю в дискуссию с людьми, которым свойственен эффект Даннинга-Крюгера, не трать время =) Если ты можешь помочь автору вопроса, то можешь дать ответ, я даже плюсану его 

Comment: о, пошел тонкий сарказм через дефис. ок, пойду подтяну квалификацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тех примерах, что скинул @overthesanity есть смысл, когда вы делаете универсальный `autoclose`, навешиваемый на любую сущность. Он расширяемый, масштабируемый, все дела.

Тогда, конечно, не стоит навешивать на все подряд хосты какую-то внутреннюю логику закрытия и прочих приблуд, которые непонятно как работают под капотом.

В вашем конкретном случае можно использовать и трюк с `focus/blur` для имитации клика снаружи. Здесь можно посмотреть [пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sn6lof)

Если внутри темплейта дропбокса будут какие-то элементы, имеющие возможность фокуса, такой кейс надо отработать отдельно, чтобы передать хосту фокус.

Comment: Столько раз уже подсказываешь. Дай Бог тебе счастья и здоровья :)))) Благодарю

Comment: нет проблем, пожалуйста!